# Bigcommerce + Node.js

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

I usually develop web apps with MEAN but I came to work for a business that uses Bigcommerce. I want to know if I can incorporate node.js applications into bigcommerce and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our API is language-agnostic, so you can use Node.js or any other language to integrate with a store. Here's a link to a community-contributed SDK that may help you get started:

https://github.com/getconversio/node-bigcommerce

This SDK provides methods for authenticating and making requests against the BigCommerce API. We are a SaaS platform, so any code that you write would be hosted on your own server. You can check out our developer documentation for more resources: https://developer.bigcommerce.com

Comment: Would the code I integrate with node-bigcommerce transfer to the bigcommerce site, or would the bigcommerce site be transfered to me?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by transfer. The node-bigcommerce API client lets your node app hook into the BigCommerce API, so your app can retrieve/update/delete data in a BigCommerce store. Your app would be hosted separately from your BigCommerce store, though.

Comment: @KarenWhite can we publish an app created in Nodejs and reactjs over bigcommerce marketplace?

Comment: @Parveenyadav Yes, you can. There are no marketplace acceptance requirements based on the language or framework you use.

Comment: Cool 
@KarenWhite Thanks for your quick response :)

Comment: @KarenWhite for using my react app with BC, Do I need to send the html from server side, I mean I need to convert my client side rendering react app to server side rendering app?(Because when BC app load the URL wants the HTML to be returned in response)